# How i create ramdisk rootfile system for linux kernel-2.6.24

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new for Linux kernel root file system. How can I create ramdisk root file system for Linux `kernel-2.6.24`.

I followed below method but when I was booting it shows `bad magic number`.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp/ramdisk.img bs=1024 count=4096
/sbin/mke2fs -f -m 0 -b 1024 tmp/ramdisk.img 4096
mkdir -p mnt/initrd
mount tmp/ramdisk.img mnt/initrd -t ext2 -o loop
mkdir mnt/initrd/bin 
mkdir mnt/initrd/sys
mkdir mnt/initrd/etc
mkdir mnt/initrd/sbin
mkdir mnt/initrd/dev  
mkdir mnt/initrd/lib
mkdir mnt/initrd/mnt
mkdir mnt/initrd/linuxrc
mknod  dev/console  c    204 32 
mknod  dev/mtdblock3 b    31 3
vi mnt/initrd/etc/fstab 

   /dev/ram0 / ext2 defaults 1 1

   sysfs      /sys sysfs defaults 0 0

gzip -9 tmp/ramdisk.img
cp -f tmp/ramdisk.img.gz .

mkimage -A arm -O linux -t 'ramdisk' -n 'INITIALRAMDISK' -c gzip -d ramdisk.img.gz ramdik.img
```

Then I tried to boot kernel image and `ramdisk.img.gz`, but it show `bad magic number`.

Comment: can you provide some more kernel log?